# c# accessing embeded file with res://

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, embedded-resource

I have in my Visual Studio project a folder named HTMLFiles which contains web resources (html, css, js files) all structured in subfolders. See screenshot:
https://www.evernote.com/l/AWlPQt30SSBLTbSwpup2oojsxJ9Bil1WND8

For the file **bootstrap.css** I've selected **"Embedded Resource"** under Build acctions and inside the html file I've tried to include it through these urls:

- **res://BuildFile.exe/HTMLFiles/styles/bootstrap.css**
- **res://BuildFile.exe/HTMLFiles/bootstrap.css**
- **res://BuildFile.exe/bootstrap.css**

But unfortunately none of them seems to work. Am I doing something wrong?

The index.html file is loaded in a WebBrowser component in a WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

So, after a lot of searches, looks like Visual Studio don't embed resources as Win32 resources. One of the solutions that I've found, but didn't tried, [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) tool to embed the resources after you build your exe file. But this means to do this every time you recompile your application.

Another fix which worked in my case because it's a single page html file was to embed all the css, js and images inside the html file.